# how can i test geocoding application in emulator

Tags: android, emulation, geocoding

i am developing application in which i want to use geocoding ,but when i using goecode

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(12.33,102.44, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                // sending back first address line and locality
                 result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
                 Toast.makeText(this, result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Logcat showing ioexception as follows

```
12-17 11:50:55.367: WARN/System.err(339): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
12-17 11:50:55.377: WARN/System.err(339):    at     android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
```

i have no android device,so i want to check this in emulator,how can resolve the problem?

Comment: WHich android sdk version you are using 2.2?

Comment: I haven't tried yet but I am sure this is not possible.

Comment: why this is not possible,can you tell the reason?

Comment: application is designed for sdk 2.1,tested in 2.3.3 emulator

Comment: Your code works fine in android 1.6 build and emulator..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using android 2.2 then It's a bug in the emulator for 2.2
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

It seems to me that this is a problem with the emulator... The getFromLocationName method seems to work just fine on the devices..

Answer (score 1):

reverse geocodeing getFromLocation method works fine when you build avd with the target as Google API 19 and also build the application target with the Google API 19.